# How to set equal distance between breaks on y-axis in ggplot2 (even though the actual distance is different)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, limit

I am trying to reproduce a plot from this paper:

https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-019-10213-0

The plot I am trying to reproduce is the one on the far left:

https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-019-10213-0/figures/2

I was able to prepare the data and plot it accordingly. The only problem I am stuck with is on how to set the breaks on the y-axis in a way that it would have an equal distance between each break (even though the actual distance between the two is different). More precisely: In the plot I want to reproduce, we have five breaks on the y-axis, ranging from 10^-1 to 10^-5: Even though the actual distance in range between 10^-1 and 10^-2 is much bigger than 10^-4 and 10^-5, the breaks have an equal distance to each other.

I read almost the whole book of Hadley Wickham on "ggplot2" to see how to do it. I tried setting the limits and breaks in the scaling layer of the plot. I tried changing the expand argument. I tried "zooming" into the graph using coord_cartesian and I also tried to change the ratio between the y- and x-axis.
The data you will find here is just an arbitrary example, so everyone can somewhat reproduce the example. In the real case, the distribution drawn ranges form 0 to 100.

```
years <- 1:10
probs <- c(0.6788, 0.1232,0.0534534,0.0034235432,0.000452342341, 0.0000454234, 0.000002354222,0.000000987, 0.0000000384, 0.0000000042352452)

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(years, probs))


my_plot <- ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(x = years, y = probs)) + xlab("L") + ylab("P(L)") 


my_plot + scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,100,20)) + scale_y_continuous(expand =
                                                                            expand_scale(mult = c(0.0001, 0.02), add = c(0.0009, 0.001)), 
                                                                          trans= "sqrt", breaks = c(0.00001, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1), 
                                                                          limits= c(0, 0.2)) + geom_point(shape = 4) + geom_line() + theme(aspect.ratio=1.2)
```

What I expect to happen is that the breaks-range on the y-axis goes from 10^-1 to 10^-5, but in a way that the distance between each break is equal.

This is my first time asking a question on Stackoverflow, I apologize for any inconvenience. Also, I made sure that there is no question related to mine, such that it is not a duplicate.

Comment: This is clearly a logarithmic scale, and if you want to emulate it you cannot use a `sqrt()` transformation. Only a logarithmic function has the property that `f(10^-5) - f(10^-4) == f(10^-4) - f(10^-3)`. And yes, an exponential function will look like a straight line on a logarithmic plot, that is kind of the whole purpose of it. If you want to emulate the figure from the Nature paper, use `scale_y_log10`, full stop.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I understand that the function will look like a straight line on a logarithmic plot. In my data, many data points are way beyond g.e. 10^-5

Is there a way to make it seem like all values below this threshold are converging to zero? Without actually excluding them (by using limits) or ignoring them when magnifying (when using coord_cartesian)?

https://ibb.co/gTT32gn

In this link, you can see that from 60 years on the x axis, the probabilities are going way below 1e-08. In this case, I want to display it in a way that they are converging to zero

Comment: Either you are trying to emulate the plot in the Nature paper, *or* you are trying to show convergence to 0. If the data converges to 0, then it will not *look* like converging to zero on a logarithmic plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is giving me the kind of y axis you want:

```r
my_plot +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,100,20)) + 
  scale_y_log10(breaks = c(0.00001, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1),
                limits= c(0.00001, 0.12),
               expand = expand_scale(mult = c(0.0001, 0.02), 
                                     add = c(0.0009, 0.001)))+
  geom_point(shape = 4) + geom_line() + theme(aspect.ratio=1.2)
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you very much for your quick response. The problem with this approach is that it completely changes the shape of the function (which turns almost completely linear). 

I am trying to set the breaks on the y axis and having the x values adjust to it (instead of changing the values of x). 

I am sorry if my question is not cleary elaborated. I would like to show a picture of the plot with the whole data but I don't know how to do it (as long as I am a new member, I cannot just upload them)

Comment: It's indeed a bit tricky to find a solution without seeing it, but maybe it can be worked out by changing the aspect.ratio argument? Is the shape of data different even when you make the x axis exactly like in the figure you want to replicate?

Comment: This is how the plot looks like with the whole data: 
https://ibb.co/hWrqqgw

And this is what happens when I use scale_y_log10 to transform it: 
https://ibb.co/SBPtxDN

To answer your question: Yes, it is. But this is not how I intend to have it.

Comment: I have tried to replicate the plot by using the lowest value in your sample and repeating it until reaching 100. Seems to me that the issue may be that the data actually go way below 10^-5? If i expand the y axis this is what I get, it looks more like the original: https://ibb.co/F5q1BrQ

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried to set the breaks and limits lower while I was working on the mentioned code of my question, but ggplot would just not do it. Would you mind sending me the code you used to produce the plot from the link?

Thank you for your efforts

Comment: Sure!! `my_plot +
  geom_point(shape = 4) + geom_line()+
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0.000000005, 0.12))+
scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,100,20))+ 
  scale_y_log10(breaks = c(0.00000001, 0.0000001, 0.000001, 0.00001, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1),
                )+ 
  theme(aspect.ratio=0.5)`

Comment: Thank you very much for your support. I am trying to fit it in a way that it would answer the question